# Hibernate + c3p0 connection reopen

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, c3p0

I am having some issues with configuring c3p0 connection pool with my hinermate connection.

I've set the wait_for my MySQL server to 180 seconds.

I also have the following parameters set in my hibernate properties file:

```
properties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", JDBC_DRIVER);
properties.put("hibernate.connection.url", JDBC_URL);
properties.put("hibernate.connection.username", JDBC_USER);
properties.put("hibernate.connection.password", JDBC_PASSWORD);
properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", false);
properties.put("hibernate.connection.provider_class", "org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider");
properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", 1);
properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", 10);
properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", 8 );
```

I have created a c3p0 properties file and added it to my resources folder. The content of this file is below:

```
c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=true
```

That is all. This is all that is left in this particular configuration file as I read that some properties can only be set in this file. Upon loading the application c3p0 is initialized I get the following log message printed out:

> INFO: Initializing c3p0 pool...
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@b014587e [
>   connectionPoolDataSource ->
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@5e2902db [
>   acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay
>   -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0,
>   connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName ->
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester,
>   debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, factoryClassLocation ->
>   null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken ->
>   1hge17r9d37v2wm1n57lrr|ba81af, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0,
>   initialPoolSize -> 1, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge
>   -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 10, maxStatements -> 8, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 1, nestedDataSource ->
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@d4187fd7 [ description ->
>   null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken
>   -> 1hge17r9d37v2wm1n57lrr|1434751, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/whatever?characterEncoding=UTF-8, properties
>   -> {user=******, password=******} ], preferredTestQuery -> null, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0,
>   testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> true,
>   unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies ->
>   false; userOverrides: {} ], dataSourceName -> null,
>   factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken ->
>   1hge17r9d37v2wm1n57lrr|2a237a, numHelperThreads -> 3 ]

It appears everything is being set.

I started configuring this connection pool because I was getting a broken pipe issue on the server 8 hours the first connection was obtained. So as a test, I set the wait_timeout no the server as I mentioned for 180 seconds and after I get the issue when trying to do a database call:

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
The last packet successfully received from the server was xxx
milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was
xxx milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured
value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or
testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing
the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the
Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this
problem.
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

I am using the following relevant maven dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

What is the easiest I set up c3p0 to avoid this broken pipe issue.

I've tried the preferredTestQuery = Select 1 approach played around with the numbers, idleConnectionTestPeriod, nothing seemed to do tha trick.

I might be missing something very simple, I could use some guidance.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Documentation to the rescue!: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToconfiguretheC3P0connectionpool (read the bits around `idleConnectionTestPeriod`)

Comment: hi. it sounds as though either the Connections you are using don't derive from the DataSource you are looking at, or something in your app is holding references to Connections rather than checking them out as-needed. can you post the full stack trace(s) for the Exception(s) you see, rather than just the message?